# ValidationSettings for aspxtextbox to validate decimal

Tags: asp.net, regex, button, devexpress

I have written a regular expression for AspxTextBox to validate decimal value as follows

```
 <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtDecimal" runat="server">
            <ValidationSettings ValidationGroup="g" RegularExpression-ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$">
            </ValidationSettings>
        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

When I am entering the digits in the textbox directly it is validating as per required, but I have a group of buttons with `0-9` and a `.` button where user can input  the text using those buttons, on clicking buttons and appending text in the textbox validation is unable to fire even if I enter wrong input, what might be the problem can some one help me

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that DevEx library uses on change event to execute validation. 
OnChange (and other Javascript events) are executed when control value is changed during user interaction and not when you change value programatically.
So, you need to execute it manually:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtDecimal" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="tb">
    <ValidationSettings ValidationGroup="g" RegularExpression-ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$"/>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>

<input type="button" onclick="tb.SetValue('10xyz');tb.Validate();"/>
```